# Problem with Exception in Application start method in IDE

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

After I tried to connect to my buttons to Controller class I've got an errorProblem with Exception in Application start method in IDE.

I did read/try all the advices like getClassLoader(), do "/sample.fxml" , put the file together with MAIN, but nothing helped. Please help me to spot the issue.

The structure is :

```
scr
   sample
         Controller
         Main
         sample.fxml
```

So, the pass "sample.fxml" looks fine. What else could be an issue?

```
 package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the _full_ [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).

Comment: Did you try the advice of using `getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml")` (which I'm pretty sure was already posted for one of a the similar questions? BTW: The stacktrace includes a line similar to `Caused by: ... Location required` (last part may also be `location not set`)? There could be a ton of other reasons involved here: non-wellformed fxml file, `Controller` class not adhereing to the requirements, module not providing access to controller class (or not declaring a module at all in some of the newer java versions), ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```